# FreeBSD 11.2: how to add the aesni plugin to strongswan?

Tags: freebsd, ipsec, plugin, strongswan

I installed strongswan using

```
pkg install strongswan
```

But now I've realized I need to have the aesni plugin enabled to optimize my IPsec tunnel.  I've already enabled aesni at the OS level.  The strongswan instructions say it's best to do at compile time but since I installed via pkg I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: It doesn't look like the aesni plugin exists for FreeBSD but I'm hoping i'm wrong...

Comment: Can you add a link to sources of this plugin?

Comment: Just a note: The _aesni_ plugin only has an effect on IKE traffic (of which there is usually little). It won't improve the performance of actual IPsec traffic, which is handled by the kernel.

Comment: @ecdsa If that's the case, what are my other options for increasing IPsec performance?  I have another thread where the answer was parallelizing IPsec to use multiple cores. I have been unable to fund very much, if any, good documentation on how to do that on FreeBSD.

Comment: If you enabled AES-NI support in the kernel(s), you should definitely switch to AES-GCM (`esp=aes128gcm16`), otherwise the negotiated integrity algorithm will be a bottleneck. But for single connections there might be an upper limit (e.g. single threaded handling to prevent packet reordering).

Comment: @ecdsa This is the right answer.  I just found a similar config independently and added it to my ipsec.conf.  I'm now getting about 8Gb network throughput using esp=aes256gcm16-modp6144 , which i can probably tune further.  My confusion was due to the fact the FreeBSD and Ubuntu show a different set of plugins.  Ubuntu shows "aes" and "aesni" in the list, whereas FreeBSD will only show "aes" in the list.

Answer (score 1):

try compiling from /usr/ports/security/strongswan port with copying strongswan to strongswan_my_aesni_edition and editing the code to compile your very own one with additional option. --enable-aesni

Problem is current one has an old version of CONFIGURE_ARGS which overwrites any modifications you add.